# How to catch default SMS app switching event?

Tags: android, sms

Is there any way to determine when user changes the default SMS app in settings? Is there any Intent action or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no system wide broadcast when the user switches the default SMS app, but what you can do is register a content observer on the SettingsProvider, by using [Settings.System.getUriFor(String name)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#7827). Pass the [default SMS application constant](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#5557) to this method and register a content observer on the Uri. You'll only know that it has changed, but not to what app, but you can use the [public API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html#getDefaultSmsPackage(android.content.Context)) for that. Also, it's worth noting that this approach will only work when your app is running.

Edit: As of Nougat, there's now an intent [broadcasted](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/telephony/ProviderUtil.java#102) when the default SMS app changes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should take a look at this: [Android Devs Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

Look out for getter Methods.

Comment: This will only help to detect the current default SMS app package name. But this is not enough.